# Android expandable GridView like Google images

Tags: android, android-gridview

I would like to create expandable GridView which will behave similar to Google images page. I would like to know how can I achieve such functionality: when I click one of the images, page expands and shows details of the picture. Is it possible to do something similar in Android?

Images grid:
[image: Google Images]

Expanded images grid:
[image: Google Images Expanded]

Comment: So any solution there?

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason you haven't received any responses is because of the wording of the question. When I first saw it I thought, something similar to expandable listview. See this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/).

But anyway, to achieve what you want, you need to set the *"expansion"* function in the OnClickListener in your GridView. I would suggest have a dialog activity with the layout you need (image with text/links/etc) and on each item click, popup the dialog. It will look very similar to what Google images has.